# Keycloak: AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to KeycloakAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, microservices, keycloak

I am developing a microservice infrastructure based on Spring Cloud. I want to secure the application with Keycloak, which is basically working fine if the user is authenticated.

If the user is not authenticated Keycloak throws the folling error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.facade.SimpleHttpFacade.getSecurityContext(SimpleHttpFacade.java:63) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.corsRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:102) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.handledRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:54) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:78) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:79) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:595) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

The security config looks as follows:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    public SecurityConfig(KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory)
    {
        this.keycloakClientRequestFactory = keycloakClientRequestFactory;
    }

    /**
   * define the actual constraints of the app.
   * @param http
   * @throws Exception
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
      super.configure(http);
      http
      .cors()
      .and()
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("user")
          .anyRequest().permitAll();
  }

    /**
     * define the session auth strategy so that no session is created
     * 
     * @return concrete implementation of session authentication strategy
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy()
    {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    /**
     * registers the Keycloakauthenticationprovider in spring context and sets its
     * mapping strategy for roles/authorities (mapping to spring seccurities'
     * default ROLE_... for authorities ).
     * 
     * @param auth
     *          SecurityBuilder to build authentications and add details like
     *          authproviders etc.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keyCloakAuthProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keyCloakAuthProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());

        auth.authenticationProvider(keyCloakAuthProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Sets keycloaks config resolver to use springs application.properties
     * instead of keycloak.json (which is standard)
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeyCloakConfigResolver()
    {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    /**
     * Spring Boot attempts to eagerly register filter beans with the web
     * application context. Therefore, when running the Keycloak Spring Security
     * adapter in a Spring Boot environment, it may be necessary to add two
     * FilterRegistrationBeans to your security configuration to prevent the
     * Keycloak filters from being registered twice.
     * 
     * @param filter
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter)
    {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    /**
     * Spring Boot attempts to eagerly register filter beans with the web
     * application context. Therefore, when running the Keycloak Spring Security
     * adapter in a Spring Boot environment, it may be necessary to add two
     * FilterRegistrationBeans to your security configuration to prevent the
     * Keycloak filters from being registered twice.
     * 
     * @param filter
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter)
    {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be much apprechiated.

Kind regards
Blacky

Answer (score 5):

In your HttpSecurity http, add `.anonymous().disable()` such that you have
your HttpSecurity like `http.anonymous().disable()`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me!
When I connected the controller globally (like this @ControllerAdvice), then at the time of logout I received an exception as in the question above. I.e. after logout, the Spring context tried to access a global service that no longer existed and the exception had time to be generated. But after adding this option "http.anonymous().disable()" everything started working correctly. Something like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my microservice architecture.
According to this [this](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-February/004810.html) answer from Stian Thorgersen all ReST-Services should be bearer-only. Thus they should accept a token, but never perform a redirect to the login page.

Therefore I extracted the UI component from the service and serve it on a separate NGINX instance. The UI performs the redirect to my Keycloak login page and adds the token to every additional GET/POST/whatever request to secured services. I changed all ReST-Services to `keycloak.bearer-only=true`, both in the service and Keycloak configuration. It now works like a charm.

Hope this helps you. 
Freddy

Answer (score 0):

We want the developers to login at the API gateway to and call services form there directly. I achieved this finally by adding a Filter that extends the basic `ZuulFilter`:

```
public class KeycloakAuthorizationFilter extends ZuulFilter
{
private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE = "Bearer";
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeycloakAuthorizationFilter.class);

@Override
public Object run()
{
    log.info("Adding authenticaton header...");
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    if (ctx.getZuulRequestHeaders().containsKey(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)) return null;

    KeycloakAuthenticationToken authentication = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();

    if(authentication == null)
    {
        log.error("Could not load authenticaton from security context!");
    }
    else if(authentication.isAuthenticated() == false)
    {
        log.error("Not authenticated!");
    }
    else
    {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if(principal != null && principal instanceof KeycloakPrincipal)
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) authentication
                    .getPrincipal();
            log.info(String.format("Constructing Header %s for Token %s", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE));
            ctx.addZuulRequestHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, String.format("%s %s", BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE, keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getTokenString()));
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public int filterOrder()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String filterType()
{
    return "pre";
}

}
```

This is just working awesome and gives you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using version `3.3.0.Final` for the starter and adapter works for me. When I change the version to `3.4.3.Final` I get the same exception.

I'm running Keycloak server 3.4.3 (standalone)...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Anyone knows a solution to use the current version of the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact same error today. Resolved by simply swapping keycloak http.AuthorizeRequest from permitAll() to authenticated() for anyRequest().

**pom.xml (unedited)**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**KeycloakSecurityConfig.java (OLD)**

```
/**
 * We require the user to be logged in for every single request
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/entry/sub/*").hasRole("roleA")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

**KeycloakSecurityConfig.java (NEW)**

```
/**
 * We require the user to be logged in for every single request
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/entry/sub/*").hasRole("roleA")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error as the topic-starter, but related to an in-house authentication token not to KeyCloak. But this question popped up first on Google, so I'm answering here.

I resolved the issue by replacing entries like:

```
<intercept-url pattern="^/login($|\?.*)" access="permitAll"/>
```

in the spring security XML config with lines like:

```
<http security="none" pattern="/login" />
```

So now Spring does not create an anonymous user token for such requests.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Spring Boot `2` dependency of Keycloak as in:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

! Note the `-2-` in the artifact id.

The Spring Boot parent being:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
```

With the Keycloak dependency being:

```
<properties>
  <keycloak.version>4.0.0.Final</keycloak.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```